# Multiple user issues: TangoService_connect(void*, TangoConfig): Internal Error: Connect failed

Tags: google-project-tango

**EDIT:** Tango Mira examples crashes if I try to run it as secondary user. With primary user, everything is fine.

Therefore, I compiled the current [point cloud example](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/tree/master/cpp_rgb_depth_sync_example) with android-ndk-r11c.
But this app crashes with the following errors:

> 05-24 17:14:36.418 10770-10770/com.projecttango.examples.cpp.pointcloud I/tango_client_api: TangoErrorType TangoService_connect(void*, TangoConfig): Connecting to Tango...
>
> 05-24 17:14:36.785 10770-10770/com.projecttango.examples.cpp.pointcloud E/tango_client_api: TangoErrorType TangoService_connect(void*, TangoConfig): Internal Error: Connect failed internally: -1
>
> 05-24 17:14:36.785 10770-10770/com.projecttango.examples.cpp.pointcloud E/tango_jni_example: PointCloudApp: Failed to connect to the Tango service witherror code: -1
>
> 05-24 17:14:36.785 10770-10795/com.projecttango.examples.cpp.pointcloud E/tango: TangoClient.cc:26 Tango Service binder transaction failed! Transaction type code = 1, status = -32.
>
> 05-24 17:14:36.785 10770-10788/com.projecttango.examples.cpp.pointcloud E/tango_client_api: virtual void TangoMortician::binderDied(const android::wp&): Internal Error: TangoService died.
>
> 05-24 17:14:36.786 10770-10788/com.projecttango.examples.cpp.pointcloud A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 10788 (Binder_1)

I've also tried run the [rgb detph sync example](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/tree/master/cpp_rgb_depth_sync_example) and getting much odder errors:

> 05-24 17:34:02.273 11564-11583/com.projecttango.examples.cpp.rgbdepthsync A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000008 (code=1), thread 11583 (GLThread 1517)
>
> 05-24 17:34:02.276 11564-11589/com.projecttango.examples.cpp.rgbdepthsync E/tango: support_point_cloud_toolbox.cc:65 TangoErrorType TangoSupport_getLatestPointCloudAndNewDataFlag(TangoSupportPointCloudManager*, TangoXYZij**, bool*) manager is nullptr.
>
> 05-24 17:34:02.336 11564-11564/com.projecttango.examples.cpp.rgbdepthsync E/tango_client_api: TangoErrorType TangoService_connect(void*, TangoConfig): Enable color camera

Has anyone experienced the same problems? Have I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

Right now the library so files are compiled with ndk-r10e.
ndk-r11c should be backward compatible. but We never try that.